# Blinds Side Mount Bracket Ripped out of Top Window Frame. Drywall too damage to reattach without reinforcing. Help

Tags: patching-drywall

We just purchased a new house and I completely missed this in the walkhthru and inspection didnt catch it either.  We only noticed it when we starting taking down all of the blinds in order to paint.  It appears that someone forcibly yanked down on the draw string of one of the blinds thus pulling it completely from the drywall.  They were basically hanging there because of their middle and opposite side support.

I have attach 3 images. One is how the blinds still installed before we noticed the issue, the second is me removing the side mounts and the last image is a clear look at the damage under the top of the window frame.

I need to repair the drywall or somehow reinforce something over the drywall in order to attach the blinds after we finish painting. Never came across something like this before.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Searched around and couldnt find anything that matched my dilemma.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There should be wood up above the drywall there (to support the opening for the window). It seems odd to me that the drapes were installed with those drywall anchors (the white things in your picture). Try probing in deeper to verify there is wood above and then use longer screws to secure your drapery bracket.

This drywall should be repaired and repainted. The metal you are seeing is the drywall corner bead which is used for the drywall finisher (the taper) to get a good straight corner. This has nothing to do with support of any kind.

Answer (score 4):

Five things:

First, secure the corner bead (corner bead nails are conventional, screws will distort the bead if you don’t practice). Either way, use plenty of fasteners to hold the corner bead down — it’ll want to move, which will mess up future steps. If you can’t get the corner bead to behave, you’ll need to replace it. Use something similar to what you remove, as paper flanged ones are nice but inappropriate here.

Second, apply a few coats of drywall compound to get to smooth-ish. You can use all purpose and wait for it to dry (easier to sand) or setting compound and shorten the dry cycles (but hard to sand). You could split the difference by building thickness with setting compound then switching to AP.

Third, spray texture from a can. Practice beforehand. This finish is called orange peel.

Prime and paint.

Last, re-mount the brackets, but stay at least an inch back from the interior wall. All these problems were caused by putting screws where they had no holding power but the ability to pull down the corner bead.

Comment: Definitely use setting compound as a filler. It’s a bit more challenging to work with but you’ll get a much stronger bond between the corner bead and the wall. It will make a difference when you go to reattach the bracket.